# Responsive grid with zoom on items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, grid

I need a responsive image grid that we can zoom on each image and all the other images should rearrange automatically on the empty spaces.

I've come to a solution which works partially:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wrapper div").click(function () {
        if ($(this).siblings().hasClass('expanded')) {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('expanded');
        }
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.wrapper div {
    width:31%;
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s;
}
.expanded {
    width:64% !important;
}
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m9kLJMi.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1fR1mQQ.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CFf5bbM.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3U2gd7I.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/N4pFnCE.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/q81AaCs.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wjjhTtW.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9fifhrM.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gz5Qdv6.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

But some items break the grid, only 1, 4 and 7 work properly.
[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/duartebriz/dp6bd3wf/)

I've come to another solution which is the [gridly plugin](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-gridly/). But I'm not able to make it responsive.

How can I make this work?

Comment: following this one because I'm curious. My guess is that it has to do with your percentage widths on the wrapper and divs

Comment: I'm hoping it's something simple like widths.

Comment: @MasterD although I don't have an answer for you I can say that it isn't something as simple as widths. The issue you're running into is how HTML markup naturally wants to re-flow. The solution _may_ be along the lines of [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Basically, you'll need to JavaScript to get elements to reflow into the empty spaces left when clicking any box besides 1, 4 and 7.